# Sorting result based on dynamic terms

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine that I have an index with the following three documents representing images and their colors.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "intensity": {
            "red": 0.6,
            "green": 0.1,
            "blue": 0.3
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "intensity": {
            "red": 0.5,
            "green": 0.6,
            "blue": 0.0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "intensity": {
            "red": 0.98,
            "green": 0.0,
            "blue": 0.0
        }
    }

]
```

It the user wants a "red image" (selected in a dropdown or in a “tag cloud”), it is very convenient to do a range query over the floats (maybe `intensity.red > 0.5`). I can also use the score of that query to get the "red-est" image ranked highest.
However, if I would like to offer free-text search, it gets harder. My solution to that would to index the documents as the following (eg use the `if color > 0.5 then append(colors, color_name)` at index time):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "colors": ["red"]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "colors": ["green", "red"]
    }
    {
        "id": 3,
        "colors": ["red"]
    }
]
```

I could now use a `query_string` or a `match` on the colors field and then search for `"red"`, but all of a sudden I lost my ranking possibilities. ID 3 is far more red than ID 1 (`0.98` vs `0.6`) but the score will be similar?

My question is: Can I have the cake and eat it too?

One solution I see is to have one index that turns free text into "keywords" which I later use in the actual search.

```
POST image_tag_index/_search {query: "redish"} -> [ "red" ]
POST images/_search {query: {"red" > 0.5}} -> [ {id: 1}, {id: 3}]
```

But then I need to fire two searches for every search, but maybe that is the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects) data type along with [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) query to get the desired result.

You need to change the way you are storing image data. The mapping will be as below:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "image": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "color": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "intensity": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index the image data as below:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "image": [
    {
      "color": "red",
      "intensity": 0.6
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "intensity": 0.1
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "intensity": 0.3
    }
  ]
}
```

The above corresponds to the first image data the you posted in the question. Similarly you can index other images data.

Now when a user search for `red` the query should be build as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "image",
            "query": {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "image.color": "red"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "image.intensity": {
                            "gt": 0.5
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "image.intensity",
                  "modifier": "none",
                  "missing": 0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can see in the above query that I have used the field value of image.intensity to calculate the score.

Comment: This looks EXACTLY like the kind of solution is was looking for. Will the nested capability make sure that the `color` and the `intensity` will match within the same sub-entity? Say that `image[0].intensity = 0.0` and `image[2].intensity = 0.6` would your search match the `color` in `image[0]` and `intensity` in `image[2]`?

Comment: Yes, nested capability make sure that the color and the intensity will match within the same sub-entity.

Comment: The query will consider color and intensity of the same sub-entity. So if an image has a entity as `{"color":"red","intensity":0.0}` and the user search for `red` the query will not match because intensity is not greater than 0.5

Comment:  Glad it helped .